# Concatenating strings in C using pointers

Tags: c

Can anyone please explain how does the increment operator work in concatenating the strings? Why does pointer `a` needs to be incremented again on the loop for pointer `b`?

```
 char aa[10] = "John";
 char bb[10] = "Meyer";

 char *a = aa;
 char *b = bb;

 while(*a)
 {
     a++;
 }

 while(*b) 
 {
     *a = *b;
     b++;
     a++;
 }
```

Comment: It's copying *one character at a time.*

Comment: Side-note: While initialized arrays happen to be zero-initialized beyond where the literal ends, in the general case, you wouldn't want to assume a `NUL` already existed after the concatenation finishes. You'd want to make your loop terminate *after* copying the `NUL` from `b`, not before, or you risk leaving `aa` unterminated (so any C-style string API would overrun the buffer while reading/writing).

Comment: You increment a in the loop because you don't want to keep overwriting the same character.

Comment: It would be clearer if you used better var names. Replace `a` with `src` (for source pointer) and `b` with `dst` (for destination pointer).

Comment: @ikegami: It's still `NUL` terminated; `aa` initializer explicitly initializes indices 0-4, but any array with an initializer implicitly initializes all "uninitialized" elements to zeroes last I checked (thus the zeroed array idiom of `type myzeroedarray[LENGTH] = {0};`). The OP copies five more characters into it, but that still leaves the tenth, implicitly zeroed character, as a `NUL` terminator. It works here, it's just not safe for *general* targets (where elements past the `NUL` terminator might not be initialized at all, or might be initialized to non-`NUL` values for whatever reason).

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
 while(*a)
 {
  a++;
 }
```

finds the *null-termination character* in string `a`.  It works, because `*a` retrieves the character at the current pointer position.  When `*a` becomes zero, the `while` condition becomes false, and `a` will contain the address of the null-termination character.

The first time through this loop:

```
 while(*b) 
 {
  *a = *b;
  b++;
  a++;
 }
```

the null termination character in string `a` will be overwritten by the first character in string `b`.  After that, the loop marches through all of the characters in `a` and copies them to `b`.  It doesn't appear to copy the null termination character, though; you'd have to add code that does this.

Comment: The `NUL` isn't copied, but it doesn't need to be (in this specific, limited case). `aa` is an explicitly initialized array; all the elements beyond the explicit initializer are implicitly zeroed, so the final index in `aa` begins as a `NUL`, and (never being overwritten) remains a (the only) `NUL` after concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

`a` needs to keep being incremented because `a` is a pointer to the character you're about to write to. If you don't increment `a` after writing to the location it points to, you end up copying *every* character in `bb` into the *same* location in `aa` (namely, the location that previously held the `NUL` terminator).

Note that your code has a flaw if you attempt to adapt it to the general case of writing to any legal C-style string known to have additional space for the additional data being concatenated. While `char aa[10] = "John";` is guaranteed to initialize indices 4-9 to the `NUL` character, strings written to uninitialized arrays won't be padded with `NUL`s for you. By not explicitly copying the `NUL` from `bb`, code that initializes `aa` with a form like this:

```
char aa[10];  // or char *aa = malloc(10);
strcpy(aa, "John");
```

will end up producing a string without a reliable `NUL` terminator; when your loop is done, `aa[8]` would be the final `r` from `"Meyer"`, but `aa[9]` would have unknown contents; any C-style string oriented API that tried to read from it would potentially run off into unrelated memory following the array, triggering undefined behavior. To fix, you can make the entire operation conditional on `b` being non-empty in the first place, then use a `do`/`while`:

```
if (*b)
{
  while(*a)
  {
    a++;
  }
  do
  {
    *a = *b;
    a++;
  } while(*b++); // Post increment required to test what we copied, then increment, so we stop after copying NUL
}
```

or explicitly `NUL` terminate after the loop:

```
while(*b) 
{
  *a = *b;
  b++;
  a++;
}
*b = '\0';
```

Comment: `if (*b)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @chux: True, but it lets you skip scanning `a` at all, and avoid a pointless `NUL` terminator copy for an empty `b`, so it might be worth it (if `b` might be empty a non-trivial percentage of the time).

Answer (score 0):

What the program is trying to do is concatenate the string `b` to the string `a`.

So first you want to point to the end of the string `a` so that you can add one character of `b` at a time.

The end of a string in C is always defined as '\0', which can be used in the while loop condition to terminate (as you can see in the first while loop).
The representation of `a` is indeed an array of characters:  'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\0'
Similar with `b`: 'M', 'e', 'y', 'e', 'r', '\0'

Once a points to the end you want to copy from `b` to `a` one character at a time:
Override '\0' with 'M'
Increment `a` and `b` to point to the next element in respective arrays
Override the array element with 'e'
Increment `a` and `b`
Override the array element with 'y'
...
and so on till the you reach the end of array `b`

```
 char aa[10] = "John";
 char bb[10] = "Meyer";

 char *a = aa;
 char *b = bb;

 // let a point to the and of the string '\0'
 while(*a) a++;

 // copy one char at a time from b to a
 while(*b) 
 {
  *a = *b;
  b++;
  a++;
 }
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in the comments on the question (and a deleted answer), `aa` is initialized on creation, which implicitly zeroes all elements not explicitly initialized. So there is a `NUL` in indices 4-9 (index 4 is explicit, due to initialization from a string literal with includes a single `NUL` at the end, indices 5-9 are implicitly zero due to not being given any explicit value). So the program as written does not have a bug; the resulting array's values are `{'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'M', 'e', 'y', 'e', 'r', '\0'}`, with the `\0` being left over from the implicit initialization of `aa`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I am not mistaken it is specified so in the C language spec. I will correct.